# Mapbox zoom to location based on url

Tags: mapbox

I have a main map landing page of the U.S. which shows my map and all the pins on it, then there are individual pages for each state with specific content related to them, that also show the map. I am wondering if it is possible to have the map zoom into the states location when that url is clicked. e.g. When you click to go to the Colorado page, the map zooms and centers on Colorado, instead of going to the default view on the main map landing page.

It would work like the geocoder, if you type Colorado, it zoom and centers on the state.

Answer (score 1):

The [initially position map with geocode](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/map-center-geocoding/) example is probably close to what you're looking for.